# Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to print records but my code returns error:

> Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given.
> Here comes code:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT
'r.Report_Id,
r.Report_Name,
r.Person_Id, 
r.Person_Name,
r.Report_Type,
r.Report_Importance,
rkr.KPI_Id,
kpis.KPI_name

FROM Reports r 

left outer join Frequencies f  on r.RefreshFrequency_Id = f.RefreshFrequency_Id 
left outer join Instructions i on r.Instruction_Id = i.Instruction_Id
left outer join ReportFamily rf on r.ReportFamily_Id = rf.ReportFamily_Id

left outer join ReportsMpCpRel rmr on r.Report_Id = rmr.Report_Id
left outer join MpCp mpc on rmr.MpCp_Id = mpc.MpCp_Id
left outer join RNA rn on mpc.Existst_RNA_Id = rn.Existst_RNA_Id

left outer join ReportsKpiRel RKR on r.Report_Id = RKR.Report_Id
left outer join KPI kpis on RKR.KPI_Id = kpis.KPI_Id

WHERE r.Report_Id' = '".$selected."'";

$stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql2);

      while( $row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt2, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) 
            {

             echo '<br>'.$row2[0];
             echo '<br>'.$row2[1];
             echo '<br>'.$row2[2];
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there's a problem with your query. A notice that you put a quote (') before `r.Report_Id` and after it:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT
'r.Report_Id,
```

AND...

```
WHERE r.Report_Id' = '".$selected."'";
```

Try to remove the quote.